# SELECT statement on top of UNION statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
select * 
from
    {
        SELECT 
            ID, CLASS, CHANGE_NUMBER AS OBJECT_NUMBER 
        FROM table_A

        UNION

        SELECT 
            ID, CLASS, CUST_NO AS OBJECT_NUMBER 
        FROM table_B
        ORDER BY ID
    } x where x.id ='5434';
```

Help me to run this query.

I am getting error "invalid table name"

Comment: Check if the plan changes when you simply run the `UNION` and add the `WHERE` to both selects. You might have to add a final `DISTINCT` to mimic the existing result.

Comment: You DO have both tables in the schema, do you?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest writing the query like this:

```
select x.*
from (SELECT ID, CLASS, CHANGE_NUMBER AS OBJECT_NUMBER FROM table_A
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ID, CLASS, CUST_NO AS OBJECT_NUMBER FROM table_B
     ) x
where x.id = '5434';
```

Notes:

- The curly braces are probably your syntax problem.
- Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`, unless you really want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.
- The `ORDER BY` is not needed.  After all, you are only choosing one `id`.
- If you do have an `ORDER BY`, it is better practice to put it in the outer query than in the subquery.

Comment: @Saurabh -  I would add to Gordon's excellent suggestions: In this case it is not clear why you need the alias `x`; and, more importantly, unless you have a very good reason, try to avoid `select *`. If in the future you need to add a column to your table, for example (for whatever reason), all other statements that rely on the output from this query will be invalidated if you use `select *` instead of spelling out the columns explicitly.

Comment: @mathguy,@gordon linoff - hello thanks for everything, I am working on plm, i am creating a web app. The database thing is new to me.In current situation i need to extract data from plm system(50-60% of data from plm database) and store it to other database as i need. also i will need to do this daily basis if any update in other database depending upon time stamp. The problem that i am facing is many of column data is id's and its string values are mapped in other tables. can you share some sample examples like this situation so that i can work on this. like anything tutorials,best examples

Comment: @mathguy since the OP had listed the columns being selected in the two queries being union'd, the select * in the outer query isn't a problem (although it wouldn't hurt to expand it out into the named columns!). Columns could be added to the underlying tables without causing any problems with this particular query.

Comment: @Boneist - Right - I didn't pay attention to that. Good point!

Answer (score 1):

Use '(' bracket instead of '{'.

```
            select * from
            (
            SELECT ID,CLASS, CHANGE_NUMBER AS OBJECT_NUMBER FROM table_A
            UNION
            SELECT ID,CLASS,CUST_NO AS OBJECT_NUMBER FROM table_B
            ORDER BY ID
            ) x where x.id ='5434';
```

Comment: hello mr.bhosale mala tumchi help pahije